# How to handle internalization in Angular on pipes and numbers

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-material

I have a very simple problem I thought, but it seems that it is quit difficult in Angular. I am dutch and I live in the Netherlands in the EU and I need to create a finance application, so with lot of currency and date's in it.

I have created a template with some custom Angular pipes and an observable which loads the data into the template. The Observable works OK.

At this moment when number 18000 comes in then the:

`verBeterEuro$ | async | currency:"EUR"`

displays €18,000.00 in the browser.

And if number percent  9 comes in then

`verbeterProcent$ | async | percent: '0.2-2':'en-NL`

displays   900.00 %
That is both completly wrong in our country.

This is my template code.

```html
<div fxLayoutGap="1%" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <h3>Verbetering:</h3>   
      <h4>{{ verBeterProcent$ | async | percent:'0.2-2':'en_NL' }}  </h4>
      <h4>{{ verBeterEuro$ | async | currency:"EUR"}}</h4>   
  </div>
```

This is my typescript code:

```
verBeterEuro$ = new Observable<number>();
verBeterProcent$ = new Observable<number>();
```

This is my code for internalization in the ngModule:

```
 providers: [{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'nl-NL'}, {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]}]
```

The number currency 18000 should be displayed as  €18.000,00 
The number precent   9 should be displayed as 9,00%.

Anybody an idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a kind of a workaround for this which is acceptable for me:

Maybe some other people also have the same challenge so here is my workaround.

In typescript add:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import nl from '@angular/common/locales/nl';

 ngOnInit() {

        registerLocaleData(nl);
}
```

In template file:

```html
<div fxLayoutGap="1%" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <h3>Verbetering:</h3>
      <h4>{{ verBeterProcent$ | async | number:'.2':'nl' }}% </h4>
      <h4>€{{ verBeterEuro$ | async | number:'.2':'nl'}}</h4>
    </div>
```

This result is ok, it is not nice but it works for now.